# Amazon S3 Signed URL with hidden encryption-key field?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption

Users upload directly to S3 through AJAX to reduce server stress. I would like to AES-256 encrypt the files using Amazon's server-side encryption.

However, I want to encrypt with a specific key on the S3 server without the user being able to see the key. I want the following to be hidden from the user on form submission. Is this not possible? The key being base64 encoded isn't useful enough -- I would need something like encrypting it with my Amazon Secret Key.

```
'x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-algorithm' => 'AES256'
'x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-key'       => base64_encode($this->user->getKey())
'x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-key-MD5'   => base64_encode(md5($this->user->getKey()))
```

Two other plausible solutions are creating custom keys for every file which rely on the initial key, or adding the encryption after the user has uploaded the file on my server (would the only way to do this be via COPYing the file and adding the encryption key?).

Comment: I see no obvious way of accomplishing this while letting the browser do direct uploads... and downloads, presumably...  What advantage do you see per-user server-side encryption keys conveying?